# web2py - creating new app - "invalid application name"

Tags: python, web2py

When I try to create a new application in web2py I get the error message "invalid application name: xxx"

Even though it created the app?

```
./web2py.py -S foo web2py.app
web2py Web Framework
Created by Massimo Di Pierro, Copyright 2007-2012
Version 2.0.6 (2012-09-02 04:44:23) stable
Database drivers available: SQLite(sqlite3), MySQL(pymysql), PostgreSQL(pg8000), IMAP(imaplib)
application foo does not exist, create (y/n)?Y
invalid application name: foo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use quotes:

```
./web2py.py -S 'foo' web2py.app
```